# vb.net input past end of file when importing CSV

Tags: vb.net

I am using vb.net to import a CSV file and using EOF

```
While Not EOF(1)
    Input(1, csv_month)
End While
```

the CSV files i import always have a line or two lines blank at the end of the file and i get an error when it gets to the end file saying `Input past end of file` and it breaks the application

Comment: That's not vb.net, that's VB5/6.

Comment: Those functions are still supported in VB.Net. It's just that you shouldn't use them. They exist only for backwards compatibility when porting old code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [TextFieldParser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. `Input()` and `EOF()` are more than a little obsolete.